# Ускорение многопоточного парсера Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Я новичок в питоне, хотелось написать многопоточный парсер. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.

Мой код:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import dbconnect
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import *
import random
import re
import time
cursor = dbconnect.connection()


def reqs(url, encode='utf-8'):
    request = Request(url)
    ua_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2467.2 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko']
    request.add_header('User-Agent', random.choice(ua_list))
    return urlopen(request).read()

def extraction(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    page = soup.find("div", class_="pages2").string
    return int(re.search(r'\d+', page).group())

def main():
    cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM labirint")
    urls = cursor.fetchall()
    parse_urls = []
    t = time.clock()
    for url in urls:
       parse_urls.append(url[0])
    pool = ThreadPool(10)
    print('Метка 1 {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))
    result = pool.map(reqs, parse_urls)
    print('Метка 2 {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))
    print(pool.map(extraction, result))
    print('Метка 3 {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Я вполне осознаю ,что он наверное написан каряво и не правильно.
В базе около сейчас около 10 ссылок. Я их забираю из базу, пишу в list, создаю пул в данном случаи 10 штук и дальше, получаю html и передаю их в BeautifulSoup, чтобы получить число из строки.

Я расставил метки и вот, что я вижу в консоли

```
Метка 1 0.030 seconds
Метка 2 5.769 seconds
[320, 320, 124, 416, 12, 713, 583, 192, 448, 384]
Метка 3 45.567 seconds
```

Я правильно понимаю,что узкое место в BeautifulSoup, почему это так?  Ведь ему достается не сложная по- идеи работа? Правильно ли я написал код? И как мне его ускорить?

Comment: 1- что  `time.clock` делает зависит от системы  (к примеру включается ли время на IO или нет), [используйте `timeit.default_timer` вместо этого](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25823885/4279) 2- что происходит если *единственное* изменение в вашем коде это замена строки: `BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")` на `BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")` 3- пробовали передать в конструктор: `parse_only=SoupStrainer('div', 'pages2')`? Подобные задачи часто скоростью сетевого ввода вывода ограничены (пропускной способностью, задержкой)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как почитал интернет, выяснил что проблема действительно в BeautifulSoup, решил использовать lxml и скорость возросла феноменально. Теперь делается все за 2 секунды.

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool
import dbconnect
from urllib.request import *
import random
import re
import time
import lxml.html as html
from lxml import etree


cursor = dbconnect.connection()


def reqs(url):
    request = Request(url)
    ua_list = [
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/46.0.2467.2 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/30.0.1599.101 Safari/537.36',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.10240',
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko']
    request.add_header('User-Agent', random.choice(ua_list))
    return urlopen(request).read()

def get_info_html(res_html):
    tree = html.fromstring(res_html)
    el = tree.xpath("//div[@class='pages2']/text()")
    test = el[0]
    return int(re.search(r'\d+', test).group())

def main():
    cursor.execute("SELECT url FROM labirint")
    urls = cursor.fetchall()
    parse_urls = []
    t = time.clock()
    for url in urls:
       parse_urls.append(url[0])
    pool = ThreadPool(10)
    print('Метка 1 {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))
    result = pool.map(reqs, parse_urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    for res in result:
        print(get_info_html(res))
    print('Метка 1 {:.3f} seconds'.format(time.clock() - t))     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```